# What does "Total loaded" mean in VisualVM?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, visualvm

What does the graph labeled "Total loaded" under "Monitor->Classes" in VisualVM mean?

The reason I ask is because under a specific test case, the "Total loaded" graph is growing  linearly but the memory (heap & permgen) remains stable.

After about 10 minutes of stress testing, VisualVM reports over 600.000 "loaded" classes. And only 450 that is "unloaded". The app is still responding at this point.

What does this really mean? 
Does it still count all classes that are cleared during GC runs? Are they different classes or different instances of classes?

Comment: Classes are not cleared during GC runs, as far as I know. Instances of classes are.

Comment: Mike, yes, you are correct. I should have said instances.

Answer (score 1):

"Total loaded" displays the total number of classes that have been loaded since the Java virtual machine has started execution.

Comment: Thanks, but what does unloaded mean if the amount of loaded classes includes all classes ever loaded since JVM start then? And how does growth of loaded classes influence performance?